# Database Design: How to store column properties?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have an web application which has many forms with many fields. Some of these fields are required and some are not, but I would like to be able to save the form values in a database table so that users can save their progress. How do I store this meta-information about columns? To be concrete, say I have a table:

```
create table form1 (
    field1 text, 
    field2 text,
    -- ...
    fieldn text
)
```

I would like to store the business logic about which fields are required somewhere, so that I can query the DB to get something like:

```
('field1_val', true, null, false, ..., 'fieldn_val', true)
```

where every odd column is are the values store in the table, and even column are whether the fields are required or not. I thought about having a separate table storing the requirement data as so:

```
create table form1_requirements (
    table_name text, 
    field_name text,
    required boolean
);
insert into form1_requirements values ('foo', 'field1', true);
insert into form1_requirements values ('foo', 'field2', false);
insert into form1_requirements values ('foo', 'fieldn', true);
```

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to do a join like that, and if it's advisable.

What is the best solution for this? I'm primarily interested in postgresql, but also mysql and sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

I would **not** store those fields like that. The fields should be in a separate table with a one-to-many relation to a forms table:

```
create table form
(
   id integer primary key,
   name text not null unique, 
   ... other columns for the form ...
);

create table field
(
  id integer primary key, 
  form_id integer not null reference form
  name text not null, 
  required boolean,
  ... other columns describing a single field, e.g. the data type ...
);
```

And the individual values should be stored in a separate table:

```
create table form_values
(
  form_id integer not null references form,
  field_id integer not null references field,
  value text,
  primary key (form_id, field_id)
);
```

The above is also know as the "Entity-Attribute-Value" design pattern.

Another option is to store that information in `json` columns:

```
create table form
(
   id integer primary key,
   name text not null unique, 
   field_definitions jsonb
);
```

In the column field_definitions you would store something like:

```
{
  "field_1": {"name": "Lastname", "required": true }}, 
  "field_2": {"name": "Firstname", "required": false }}
}
```

You should still use a second table to store the actual field values. You could also store all values for a single form in one JSON column.

Comment: That certainly does solve the problems I'm having.... but I can't help but think that it would make the usage of the data a pain in the butt because if I wanted to do a simple SELECT for all form values, I'd have to do a self-join per column, right?

Comment: @user3243135: yes, that's one of the downside of such a generic data model. Storing that within a single JSON column would make _that_ part easier

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define the columns you need as `NOT NULL`?

```
create table form1 (
    field1 text not null, 
    field2 text,
    -- ...
    fieldn text not null
);
```

The ones declared `not null` are then required.

Comment: I want to be able to store incomplete forms, as I said in the question.

Comment: So using Gordon’s idea store the incomplete form data in a seperate table, when the first insert fails, but use the meta data from the dB dictionary to define this vis the the not null constraint . Can even keep comments and default values in here